# National Travel document for ESTA application

Tags: esta

Is a Resident Alien Card issued to a Spanish citizen to reside in the US considered a national identity to travel? Question of the ESTA application

Comment: Do you mean Green Card?

Comment: If you are a US Permanent Resident, you do not need an ESTA.

Comment: @mlc more accurately, if you are a US permanent resident, you _are not eligible for ESTA_ and should not apply for ESTA.

Answer (score 7):

No, a US Resident Alien card (commonly referred to a Green Card) is NOT considered a National Identity card.

Given you specifically asked in the context of an ESTA application it's worth pointing out that if you hold a current/active Green Card then you do NOT need to apply for an ESTA before travelling to the US. ESTA is only requires for people entering the US under the Visa Waiver Program, which is not relevant to people that have a valid US visa, a valid US Green Card, or are a US citizen.

If the Permanent Residence status is no longer valid/has expired/etc, then the ESTA (or a visa) would be required for travel to the US.

Comment: "If the Green Card is no longer valid/has expired/etc, then the ESTA (or a visa) would be required for travel to the US." Airlines are allowed to treat an expired 10-year green card as valid for travel to the US, as far as the US government is concerned. Also, someone with a lost or expired green card who has been abroad for less than 1 year can obtain carrier documentation to return to the US by filing I-131A at a US consulate abroad.

Comment: "If the Green Card is no longer valid/has expired/etc, then the ESTA (or a visa) would be required for travel to the US." No, the green card should be used unless the traveller has abandoned permanent residency, in which case it should be surrendered at an embassy. Of course, depending on their absences, the CBP could believe permanent residency to be abandoned, in which case they can refer to an immigration judge